# A number which is just the odd (or even) bits of another number

Tags: integer, bit-manipulation

Say I have some 128-bit number n:

0b10010101110101010101...

And I want to construct two new 64-bit numbers, one of which consists of the odd bits in n, and one of which consists of the even bits in n. I can do this by masking each bit individually and setting it, but I am wondering if there is a faster algorithm.

This is the algorithm I used (in Ruby) to do this:

```
n=0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

odds=0
evens=0
0.upto(63) do |i|
  even_mask =  1 << (2*i)
  odd_mask  =  1 << ((2*i)+1)
  pos_mask  =  1 << i
  evens = (evens | pos_mask) if (n & even_mask) != 0
  odds  = ( odds | pos_mask) if (n & odd_mask) != 0
end

puts odds.to_s(16)
>> ffffffffffffffff

puts evens.to_s(16)
>> 0
```

Is there a more efficient way to do it, using say a constant or log(n_bits) number of bitwise operations?

Comment: There is a fast way to do the OPPOSITE of what you're asking: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#InterleaveTableObvious

Answer (score 2):

You could precalculate some k-bit-wide lookup tables (with k being something like 4, 8, or 16) holding the "odd" and "even" bits of the lookup index, then do n/k table lookups and reassemble them with shifting and masking.

For a given k, you still need O(n_bits) operations for each bit pattern processed, with some overhead to build the tables. But if you're doing this operation lots of times, it'll probably still be more efficient to use the lookup tables rather than doing it one bit at a time.

Comment: I like your idea. I need to accomplish the same thing, only I have to uninterleave N separate channels, where n can vary from 2 to 1000! (I am using BigInegers.)